# importing images and placing them in an array in powerpoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm new to powerpoint vba programming. I'm struck with a problem, i have a macro script which basically takes the path to the folder where my images are there and it then places one image per slide. 
Now i want the macro script to prompt the user whether to place 4 or 6 or 8 images in a slide. the output which i'm expecting is below:

[image]

i know that this can be done by "Insert photoalbum" but the problem is it has only option for four images per slide. So that is the reason i'm writing a macro.
this is the code which i used:

```
Sub CreatePictureSlideshow()
  Dim presentation
  Dim layout
  Dim slide

  Dim FSO
  Dim folder
  Dim file
  Dim folderName

  ' Set this to point at the folder you wish to import JPGs from
  ' Note: make sure this ends with a backslash \
  folderName = "C:\Users\hamanda\Desktop\B2_images\"

  ' Delete all slides and setup variables
  Set presentation = Application.ActivePresentation
  If presentation.Slides.Count > 0 Then
     presentation.Slides.Range.Delete
  End If
  Set layout = Application.ActivePresentation.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(1)
  Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

  ' Retrieve the folder's file listing and process each file
  Set folder = FSO.GetFolder(folderName)
  For Each file In folder.Files

     ' Filter to only process JPG images
     If LCase(Mid(file.Name, Len(file.Name) - 3, 4)) = ".png" Then

        ' Create the new slide and delete any pre-existing contents
        Set slide = presentation.Slides.AddSlide(presentation.Slides.Count + 1, layout)
        While slide.Shapes.Count > 0
          slide.Shapes(1).Delete
        Wend

        ' Add the picture
        slide.Shapes.AddPicture folderName + file.Name, False, True, 10, 10

        ' Optional: create a textbox with the filename on the slide for reference
        '   Dim textBox
        '   Set textBox = slide.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 10, 10, 200, 200)
        '   textBox.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = file.Name
     End If
  Next

End Sub
```

So now how can i modify this for inserting 4 or 6 or 8 images in a slide help me with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Tested**

Funtion [Mod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se0w9esz.aspx)

And properties of shape like Left,Top,Height,Width will help you to get solution for your problem.

see the comments in the code for better understanding :). Let me know if you need further help .

Below code will insert four images in single slide.. if you look to insert more images then you have to insert elseif and Modvalue

```
   Sub CreatePictureSlideshow()
      Dim presentation
      Dim layout
      Dim slide
    
      Dim FSO
      Dim folder
      Dim file
      Dim folderName
      
      Dim i As Integer
    
      'Change the folder as per your needs
      
      folderName = "C:\Temp\C\"
     i = 1
      
      Set presentation = Application.ActivePresentation
      If presentation.Slides.Count > 0 Then
         presentation.Slides.Range.Delete
      End If
      
      Set layout = Application.ActivePresentation.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(1)
      Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
      Set folder = FSO.GetFolder(folderName)
      
      ' loop though each image in the folder
      
      For Each file In folder.Files
    
         If LCase(Mid(file.Name, Len(file.Name) - 3, 4)) = ".jpg" Then
    
    If i Mod 4 = 1 Then
    ' For 1,5,9 .... images
            Set slide = presentation.Slides.AddSlide(presentation.Slides.Count + 1, layout)
            
            While slide.Shapes.Count > 0
              slide.Shapes(1).Delete
            Wend
    
            Set img = slide.Shapes.AddPicture(folderName + file.Name, False, True, 200, 200)
             With img
             .Left = 0
             .Top = 0
             .Height = 300
              .Width = 300
             End With
    
    ElseIf i Mod 4 = 2 Then
    ' For 2,6,10 .... images
    
    Set img = slide.Shapes.AddPicture(folderName + file.Name, False, True, 200, 200)
             With img
             .Left = 301
             .Top = 0
             .Height = 300
              .Width = 300
             End With
    
    
    ElseIf i Mod 4 = 3 Then
    ' For 3,7,11 .... images
    
    Set img = slide.Shapes.AddPicture(folderName + file.Name, False, True, 200, 200)
             With img
             .Left = 0
             .Top = 301
             .Height = 250
              .Width = 250
             End With
    
    Else
    ' For 4,8,12 .... images
    
    Set img = slide.Shapes.AddPicture(folderName + file.Name, False, True, 200, 200)
             With img
             .Left = 300
             .Top = 301
             .Height = 250
              .Width = 250
             End With
    End If
    
           
         End If
     i = i + 1
      Next
    
    End Sub
```

Comment: i'll try it and let you know

Comment: i've run the code it's giving a run time error 424:Object required. HOw to fix that

Comment: have you step though the code using f9 ? if so where you are getting error ?

Comment: yeah sry it works now i forgot to change the debug mode,Now ihave one small quest is it possible to take the files in order they appear in the folder to the slides@Sathish

Comment: As far as i know .. we can loop though the each image in folder(works like details mode in folder) .. you can raise separate  question with some more details .. so that you can get more answers from experts

Comment: The order of the files as you see them in the folder will depend on how you have Explorer set to sort them ... name (ascending/descending), date, size, type etc.  This code will, I'm fairly sure, return the files in directory order ... the order in which they were created.  If you want them sorted by name/etc.  you'd need to read them into an array, sort the array then add them to PPT from the array.

Comment: @SathishK i have a problem with your code it's not working for .png images it is giving an error saying "object required" and when i press debug option it poiniting to Set img = slide.Shapes.AddPicture(folderName + file.Name, False, True, 200, 200)